# Hello World Android help in understanding Bundle

Tags: android

A basic doubt. I m working with the following code.

```
package com.example.helloandroid;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class HelloAndroidActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}
}
```

**What will the Bundle savedInstanceState contain?**
 
Since oncreate is an overridden method, I feel that "savedInstanceState" will not get any information from the base class.
If that is the case, super.onCreate(savedInstanceState) cannot be executed.
Please help me in where my understanding is going wrong.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

it will have whatever you put there in your `@Override` of `onSaveInstanceState`.

`onSaveInstanceState` will be called whenever the system needs to save its state for later re-creation. change of orientation is one of these cases. if you switch between portrait and landscape, `onSaveInstanceState` will be called, and you'll fill in the bundle that's passed in. then `onCreate` will be called with that same bundle.

so then whenever `onCreate` is called with a savedInstanceState, you should initialize your activity from this instead of from scratch.

EDIT: explanation copied from comments:

in your `onSaveInstanceState` you will call the Bundle's `putXxxx` methods -- whatever values represent the current state of your activity, you'll "put" that into the Bundle. then you'll get back that same bundle in a future onCreate so you can re-create your activity from where you left off.

if you're not implementing `onSaveInstanceState`, the `savedInstanceState` parameter will be null in `onCreate` and you can safely ignore it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response....As of now,I have not used onSaveInstanceState in my code.So,how will the code know what to take for "savedInstanceState" ?.......From basic java experience, I do not know how an argument of a derived class is getting initialized without my intervention.

Comment: in your `onSavedInstanceState` you will call the Bundle's putXxxx methods -- whatever values represent the current state of your activity, you'll "put" that into the Bundle. then you'll get back that same bundle in a future `onCreate` so you can re-create your activity from where you left off.

Comment: I got the point what u r saying......but my doubt is related to the above code. In that code,I have not used onSaveInstanceState. So how is the code knowing what value to take for "savedInstanceState" ?

Comment: aha -- yes, of course. if `savedInstanceState` is null in `onCreate` you can safely ignore it. which is to say, if you're not implementing `onSaveInstanceState` that parameter will be null in `onCreate`